# How do you make some checkbox in checked status on page load using javascipt, no jQuery?

Tags: javascript

```html
<div class="panel-collapse collapse show" id="filter-location-4316069">
  <div class="panel-body">
    a
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Ajax<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="157" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Barrie<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="276" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Brampton<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="272" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> British Columbia<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="280" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Burlington<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="154" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Cambridge<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="278" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like some checkboxes with value (157, 276, 278 for example) in "checked" status when the page loads.

Total newbie here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When page is loaded this script check if exist inputs with values fom array `list` if this values exist. The script automatically add `checked`

```js
var wrap = document.querySelector('.panel-body');
var list = [157, 276, 278];

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var x = wrap.querySelector('input[value="' + list[i] + '"]')
    if (x) {
        x.checked = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-collapse collapse show" id="filter-location-4316069">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="chk-wrap"> Ajax<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="157"
                    class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or"
                    data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="chk-wrap"> Barrie<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="276"
                    class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or"
                    data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="chk-wrap"> Brampton<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="272"
                    class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or"
                    data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="chk-wrap"> British Columbia<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter"
                    value="280" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or"
                    data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="chk-wrap"> Burlington<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="154"
                    class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or"
                    data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="chk-wrap"> Cambridge<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="278"
                    class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or"
                    data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`checked` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) :

```html
<div class="panel-collapse collapse show" id="filter-location-4316069">
  <div class="panel-body">
    a
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Ajax<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="157" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or" checked><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Barrie<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="276" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or" checked><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Brampton<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="272" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> British Columbia<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="280" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Burlington<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="154" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Cambridge<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="278" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or" checked><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or via javascript:

```
element.checked = true;
```

example:

```
var inputs =document.querySelectorAll(".form-check-input"); 
inputs.forEach(
  function(currentValue, currentIndex, listObj) {
    if(currentValue.value==157||currentValue.value==276||currentValue.value==278) currentValue.checked=true;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript:

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter"]');
checkboxes.forEach(cb => cb.checked = true);
```

```html
<div class="panel-collapse collapse show" id="filter-location-4316069">
  <div class="panel-body">
    a
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Ajax<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="157" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark" checked></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Barrie<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="276" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or" checked><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Brampton<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="272" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> British Columbia<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="280" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Burlington<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="154" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="chk-wrap"> Cambridge<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="278" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or" checked><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let checkedArr = ['272','276','278'];
checkedArr.forEach((id)=>{
 document.querySelector(`input[value="${id}"]`).checked = true;
});
```

```html
<div class="panel-collapse collapse show" id="filter-location-4316069">
                    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="chk-wrap"> Ajax<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="157" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="chk-wrap"> Barrie<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="276" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="chk-wrap"> Brampton<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="272" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="chk-wrap"> British Columbia<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="280" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="chk-wrap"> Burlington<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="154" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="chk-wrap"> Cambridge<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="278" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                       </div>
                    </div>
    </div>
```

Simply USe the `value` attribute to select the desired checkbox and add checked to it

```js
document.querySelector('input[value="157"]').checked=true;
document.querySelector('input[value="276"]').checked=true;
document.querySelector('input[value="278"]').checked=true;
```

```html
<div class="panel-collapse collapse show" id="filter-location-4316069">
                <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="chk-wrap"> Ajax<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="157" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="chk-wrap"> Barrie<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="276" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="chk-wrap"> Brampton<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="272" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="chk-wrap"> British Columbia<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="280" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="chk-wrap"> Burlington<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="154" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="chk-wrap"> Cambridge<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="278" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                   </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Simply use the `forEach` loop to minimum JS code and supply the value data to the array on which you want to `checked` true

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get all checkboxes and iterate over it and check if its value is equal to `157`, `276`, `278`.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
if(inputs){
   for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
      if(inputs[i].value === '157' || inputs[i].value === '276' || inputs[i].value === '278'){
          inputs[i].checked = true;
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-collapse collapse show" id="filter-location-4316069">
                <div class="panel-body">
        a           <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="chk-wrap"> Ajax<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="157" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="chk-wrap"> Barrie<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="276" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="chk-wrap"> Brampton<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="272" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="chk-wrap"> British Columbia<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="280" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="chk-wrap"> Burlington<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="154" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="chk-wrap"> Cambridge<input type="checkbox" name="jvbpd_list_multiple_filter" value="278" class="form-check-input" data-tax="listing_location" data-condition="or" data-term-condition="or"><span class="form-check-label checkmark"></span></label>
                   </div>
                </div>
</div>
```